# Use of FFT in order to multiply two positive integers of $n$ digits

Tags: algorithms, multiplication, fourier-transform

> We're given two positive integers $t$ and $s$ of length $n$ in binary representation.
>
> Suppose we divide the numbers into ${n \over k}$ blocks of size $k=\lg n$
>   using FFT algorithm.
>
> Suppose that the multiplications that occur during recursive calls do not increase the length of the resulting numbers (not necessarily true in reality but can be supposed for the sake of the algorithm) therefore the multiplications can be performed in $Θ(k^2)$ bit operations.
>
> How can we complete the computation is $O(n\lg^2n)$?

We can represent $x$ and $y$ as a sum. For example:
$$
t = t_0\cdot 2^0+t_1\cdot 2^1 +...+ t_{{n \over k} -1}\cdot 2^{{n \over k} -1}
$$

Essentially powers of two are analogous to $x$'s in a polynomial $a_n\cdot x^n+...+a_1\cdot x^1+a_0\cdot x^0$.

Therefore we can use FFT on the coefficients vector of $t$.

Let $\bar t, \bar s$ be the coefficients vectors of their corresponding sum representation.

Then:
$$
q = \operatorname{FFT}(\bar t) \cdot \operatorname{FFT}(\bar s)\\
p= \operatorname{iFFT}(\bar q)
$$
where $\operatorname{iFFT}$ is the inverse FFT algorithm and $q$ is the point-wise result of $\bar t\cdot \bar s$. FFT operations run time is $O({n  \over k}\lg{{n \over k}})$ but we know that the length of the result of bit multiplication of $x_i\cdot y_i$ is still $k$ so the run time is really $O(k^2\cdot {n  \over k}\lg{{n \over k}}) = O({nk}\lg{{n \over k}})$.

I'm not sure how I can complete the algorithm in $O(n\lg^2 n)$ time from this step though.

Comment: I don't really see what's missing. If you plug in $k = \lg n$ then you get $O(n\lg^2 n)$.

Comment: You don't mention the propagation step following the convolution : $11 \ast 11 = 121 = 201 = 1001$, nor the size needed to store the complex numbers.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but we still need to multiply the coordinates of the resulting vector with ${2n \over k}$ powers of $2$. Is time complexity of this step also $O(k^2\cdot {n  \over k}\lg{{n \over k}}) = O({nk}\lg{{n \over k}})$?

Comment: The answer really depends on the computation model, but usually multiplying by powers of 2 is easy (in the bit complexity model, free).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if we're using bit shifting then if the resulting vector is $\sum_{i=0}^{2n\over k}p_i\cdot 2^i$ then the length of each coordinate $p_i$ is $k$ but the length of $2^i$ can be of length $O({2n})=O(n)$ then the time complexity could be ${2n}\cdot n = O(n^2)$ no?

Comment: No. Shifting is for free in the bit complexity model, since you're just renaming bits. If you're using a different model then it depends on the allowed operations, but shifting shouldn't be the computation-intensive part of the algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus ok thanks! Is the index notation I used to describe the initial representation of $t$ as the sum $t = t_0\cdot 2^0+t_1\cdot 2^1 +...+ t_{{n \over k} -1}\cdot 2^{{n \over k} -1}$ correct? because we're breaking $t$ into ${n \over k}$ blocks so maybe the notation should be: $t=t_0\cdot 2^0+t_k\cdot 2^k+...+ t_{2k}\cdot 2^{2k}$?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you further. If you have any more questions, I suggest contacting a TA.

Comment: I wish I had one :) I study at open university. but you've helped a lot already.